# Newly built gcc not being used even after setting $PATH

Tags: linux, gcc

My server has GCC4 and I need newer version, so I built GCC7.3.0 and added the path to the $PATH variable. After this, `gcc -v` and `g++ -v` points to the correct version:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/users/home/m/GCC-7.3.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/m/gccbuild/../srcdir/configure --prefix=/home/m/GCC-7.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC)
```

However, I tried compiling a simple `hello.cc` program and `ldd a.out` gives:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe609bb000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa0bff67000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa0bfc65000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa0bfa4f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa0bf681000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa0c026e000)
```

From [here,](https://www.reddit.com/r/gcc/wiki/index) was expecting something like:

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /users/home/m/GCC-7.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000123456789000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /users/home/m/GCC-7.3.0/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000123456ABC000)
```

Also, `cat /proc/version` gives:

```
Linux version 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Mar 31 23:36:51 UTC 2020
```

EDIT:

Output to `grep configure config.status` within gcc build directory:

```
# Generated by configure.
# Compiler output produced by configure, useful for debugging
# configure, is in config.log if it exists.
configured by /home/s18002/gccbuild/../srcdir/configure, generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64,
ac_configure_extra_args=
  ac_configure_extra_args="$ac_configure_extra_args --silent" 
  set X '/bin/sh' '/home/s18002/gccbuild/../srcdir/configure'   '--prefix=/home/m/GCC-7.3.0' '--disable-multilib' '--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go,lto' $ac_configure_extra_args --no-create --no-recursion
"L) $$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/scripts/testsuite_flags --build-includes; else echo -funconfigured-libstdc++-v3 ; fi` -L$$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/li"\
S["extra_host_zlib_configure_flags"]=""
S["extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags"]="--enable-shared"
S["extra_linker_plugin_configure_flags"]=""
S["extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags"]="--with-gmp-    builddir=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp"
S["extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags"]="--with-mpfr-include=$$s/mpfr/src --with-mpfr-lib=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpfr/src/.libs"
S["extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags"]="--with-gmp-include=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp --with-gmp-lib=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp/.libs"
S["extra_mpfr_configure_flags"]="--with-gmp-include=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp --with-gmp-lib=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp/.libs"
S["extra_liboffloadmic_configure_flags"]=""
S["TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS"]="/home/s18002/gccbuild/../srcdir/configure --prefix=/home/s18002/GCC-7.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib"
# Let's still pretend it is `configure' which instantiates (i.e., don't
configure_input='Generated from '`
`' by configure.'
  configure_input="$ac_file.  $configure_input"
case $configure_input in #(
   ac_sed_conf_input=`$as_echo "$configure_input" |
*) ac_sed_conf_input=$configure_input;;
s|@configure_input@|$ac_sed_conf_input|;t t
```

The package I was trying to install got installed, which means it is using gcc7. How can I make sure GCC7 is used locally for all my purposes?

Comment: Check first what `gcc --version` and `g++ --version` tells you! Show in your question the exact `configure` command that you did use when compiling GCC (e.g. output of `grep configure config.status` in your GCC build directory)

Comment: they point to the correct version @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: My guess is that you `configure`-d your GCC wrongly. Or perhaps your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is wrong

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I've added output of `grep configure config.status` to the question, the package I was having problem in installing has installed, which means it is using gcc7, but I'm not sure why the other stuff isn't working. I didn't make changes to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, am I supposed to?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling with **g++** and not gcc:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcbdd71000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3b23c32000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3b24000000)

$ g++ test.c
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffedc577000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f745ed73000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f745ea71000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f745e85b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f745e48d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f745f07a000)
```

Comment: ya I tried both, updated question with output of g++. Even then why is `cat /proc/version` still giving gcc4 instead of gcc7

Comment: `/proc/version `gives gcc version used to compile Linux kernel: it cannot be modified unless you recompile and use this new  kernel.

Comment: ohh.. and how do I know from output of `ldd a.out` if it's using gcc7?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to know. Maybe `objdump` command can be used, but not sure.